# How to detect if javascript is executing on page

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, webdriver

Is there a way to detect if javascript is executing a script using either JQuery, javascript, WebDriver, or C# (like a browser API or something)?

For example, say I'm on a webpage and I just selected a U.S. State (let's say California) from a picklist, and some javascript is now loading a second picklist with all the cities found in California.  How can I detect if javascript is executing, and when it has finished?

I'm running into problems with WebDriver since it doesn't know how to wait for a script to stop executing aside from pausing for a few seconds.

Comment: if you're using IE use the developer tools and debug the script.

Comment: This is for test automation, so unfortunately that isn't an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question could be taken several ways.

Are you trying to see if javascript is enabled on the browser from your server-side code? I have done this by sending a small page with a form field and some javascript to populate that field and post-back. if the post-back doesn't happen, the page says something about 'javascript must be enabled.' If it DOES postback, I know Javascript is enabled.

If you're are client-side and you need to wait for something to complete, like loading your US State pull-down you need to wire up on-completion type events. Browsers are asynchronous by nature (that's a good thing) so you need to 'register' callbacks for key things to know when they've completed.

Without specific markup or situations it's tough to offer more.

Comment: I don't particularly care if javascript is enabled or not, just whether it's currently running a script or not.  I need to be able to detect if javascript is running on a very general basis, perhaps in a function like IsJavascriptCurrentlyDoingSomething().

Comment: Wouldn't IsJavascriptCurrentlyDoingSomething() return true because IsJavascriptCurrentlyDoingSomething() is running?

Comment: LOL, I suppose it would.  I think that's my answer right there - unless I can bind to a "javascriptIsRunning" event (which doesn't exist), then what I'm asking for isn't possible..

Comment: Marking as accepted answer, thanks for your responses everyone, you've given some great insight that has been very helpful to me!

Answer (score 3):

you can create a callback function, when the call for the picklist ends it triggers the callback.

example:  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html", //your url to call
  success: function(){ //your function that is a callback
    $(this).addClass("done");
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm afraid I need something a little more generalized; I don't have access to the code base to be able to add callback functions.  I can execute javascript/jquery with WebDriver, but that's about it.

Answer (score 1):

Nice way to detect if some functions are running is to make them to signal when they are start working and when they are done. For example, function can trigger to some page element that it's working (I'm using jQuery here):

```
function Announcer() {
   $('body').triggerHandler('startworking')

    //... do something useful...

   $('body').triggerHandler('endworking');
   return something;
}
```

so you can listen the element for the events and control how your code is running by callback functions:

```
$('body').bind('startworking', function () {
  alert('Whoa, Announcer is started to work');
})

$('body').bind('endworking', function () {
   alert('Announcer just ended');
})
```

It's simple mechanism of pub/sub concept.
By the way, you can read for some more advanced technique, like OpenAjax specification and it's Hub realisation:
http://www.openajax.org/member/wiki/OpenAjax_Hub_2.0_Specification

Oh, if pub/sub is not exactly what you want, maybe jQuery Deffered object will be helpfull:
http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Comment: As mentioned above, I don't have access to the code base to be able to add callback functions.  Thanks for the links to OpenAjax and jQuery deferred objects, I'll look into those, they may be possibilities..

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do something if JavaScript is not Enabled ,like adding tags `<noscript>Do Whatever You Want</noscript>` so you can invalidate or something ,be creative .

Answer (score 0):

You can actually make an ajax call to fetch the data for the city in javascript. Doing this using an XMLHttp object actually allows you to make calls asynchronously. With this you can even attach a Javascript function which gets invoked on its state change. For example,

```
try {

  xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");

} catch (e) {

  try {

   xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

  } catch (E) {

   xmlhttp = false;

  }
}

.....
.....

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {

  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {

    alert(xmlhttp.getAllResponseHeaders())

  }
}
```

Comment: I've seen first-posters not doing any formatting at all, but undertaking an effort to enclose each individual line in backticks is just wow! @Anubhav Ranjanm: just select your code and press `Ctrl+K`.